# Getting word from string

Tags: python, regex

How can i get word **example** from such string:

```
str = "http://test-example:123/wd/hub"
```

I write something like that

```
print(str[10:str.rfind(':')])
```

but it doesn't work right, if string will be like

```
"http://tests-example:123/wd/hub"
```

Comment: You can use `(?<=-).+(?=:)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mm03JJ/1)

Comment: With re? Like re.search('(?<=-).+(?=:)', str)?

Comment: Yes. Let me add and illustrate in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to capture the value preceded by `-` and followed by `:` using [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
(?<=-).+(?=:)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mm03JJ/1/)**

Python code,

```
import re

str = "http://test-example:123/wd/hub"

print(re.search(r'(?<=-).+(?=:)', str).group())
```

Outputs,

```
example
```

Non-regex way to get the same is using these two splits,

```
str = "http://test-example:123/wd/hub"

print(str.split(':')[1].split('-')[1])
```

Prints,

```
example
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following non-regex because you know example is a 7 letter word:

```
s.split('-')[1][:7]
```

For any arbitrary word, that would change to:

```
s.split('-')[1].split(':')[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

many ways

using splitting:

```py
example_str = str.split('-')[-1].split(':')[0]
```

This is fragile, and could break if there are more hyphens or colons in the string.

using regex:

```py
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'-(.*):')
example_str = pattern.search(str).group(1)
```

This still expects a particular format, but is more easily adaptable (if you know how to write regexes).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why do you want to get a particular word from a string. I guess you wanted to see if this word is available in given string.

if that is the case, below code can be used.

```
import re
str1 = "http://tests-example:123/wd/hub"
matched = re.findall('example',str1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Split on the `-`, and then on `:`

```
s = "http://test-example:123/wd/hub"
print(s.split('-')[1].split(':')[0])
#example
```

Answer (score 0):

using re

```
import re

text = "http://test-example:123/wd/hub"

m = re.search('(?<=-).+(?=:)', text)
if m:
    print(m.group())
```

Answer (score 0):

Python strings has built-in function [find](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20find#str.find):

```
a="http://test-example:123/wd/hub"
b="http://test-exaaaample:123/wd/hub"
print(a.find('example'))
print(b.find('example'))
```

will return:

```
12
-1
```

It is the index of found substring. If it equals to `-1`, the substring is not found in string. You can also use **in** keyword:

`'example' in 'http://test-example:123/wd/hub'`

`True`